# Replace the some special symbol from query string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get these type of params PropertyType[] in my url instead of PropertyType[0].How to replace it?

Actual URL

> City=Antwerp,Archbold,Berkey&PropertyType[0]=Residential&minbed=1&minbath=1&min_price=10000&max_price=2500000

I want these type of url

> City=Antwerp,Archbold,Berkey&PropertyType[]=Residential&minbed=1&minbath=1&min_price=10000&max_price=2500000

```
var serializeData = $('#searchstring').val();
    console.log(serializeData);
    var data = JSON.stringify(serializeData);
    var url1 = data.replace(/['"]/g,'');        
    var url = url1.replace(/\+/g,' ');
    var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(url);
```

Comment: Please update the question with the attempted code.

Comment: Post the value of `searchstring`

Comment: Why not this `\`City=Antwerp,Archbold,Berkey&PropertyType[0]=Residential&minbed=1&minbath=1&min_price=10000&max_price=2500000\`.replace(/PropertyType\[\d+\]/,'PropertyType[]')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\d` regular expression to replace all digits that appear in `[]`

```js
var url = 'City=Antwerp,Archbold,Berkey&PropertyType[0]=Residential&minbed=1&minbath=1&min_price=10000&max_price=2500000';

var regEx = new RegExp(/\[\d+\]/,'gim');

var newURL = url.replace(regEx, (match) => '[]');

console.log(newURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace these using regex in js

```
url = ""your_url"
new_url = url.replace(/([\d])/g, '')
```